# How do i transfer apps from one iPhone to another

Tags: iphone, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store, mobile-safari

How do i transfer apps from one iPhone to another. in Android we do the same using Zapya, where we can send applications. is there any way in Iphone for the same?

Comment: You share it from the app store app page and the other phone downloads it from the app store.

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct-transfer of apps that I'm aware of. If the phones are signed into the same iTunes account the app should be downloadable from the app store on the 2nd phone, assuming the phone's iOS version & model is compatible.

Alternatively you can transfer your apps from the 1st iPhone to iTunes and then onto the 2nd iPhone but this only works if they're both signed into the same iTunes account.